# Thrice Differentiable function problem

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

We have the following problem

> Let a function $f:R\rightarrow R$ be a thrice differentiable function such that $f(x),f'(x),f''(x),f'''(x)>0 \,\forall x\in R$. Given $f'''(x)<f(x),\forall x\in R$. Then $f'(x)<nf(x)\,\forall x\in R$. Find $n$

This question is quite mind-boggling, and I can't figure out where to start.

I tried to do the following:

First I multiplied $f''(x)$:
$$f''(x)f'''(x)<f(x)f''(x)$$
since $(f'(x))^2>0$
$$f''(x)f'''(x)<f(x)f''(x)+(f'(x))^2$$
We get $$f''(x)f'''(x)<(f(x)f'(x))'$$
Integrating:
$$\frac{1}{2}(f''(x))^2<f(x)f'(x)$$
However, now I am stuck and I can't think of another way to tackle this problem. Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a typo in the "We get: $f''(x)f''(x)<(f(x)f'(x))'$"; it should be $f''(x)f'''(x)<(f(x)f'(x))'$.

Comment: This question has been asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3744510/smallest-c-such-that-fcf-holds-for-all-f-such-that-f-f-f-f0-and?noredirect=1&lq=1)