# Prove that $f'(x)<kf(x)$. What can the biggest value of k

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, inequality, contest-math

Let $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a thrice differentiable function such that $f(x)$,$f'(x)$,$f''(x)$ and $f'''(x)$ are all positive $\forall x\in \mathbb R$. Also it is known that $$f'''(x)<f(x)$$ $\forall x\in \mathbb R$.

To prove : $f'(x)<kf(x)$ $\forall x\in\mathbb R$  where $k>1$

My Attempt:

I tried to solve the differential equation $$\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}=y$$ and obtained
$$y=C_{1}e^x+C_{2}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}x\right)+C_{3}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}x\right)$$.

But how do I work around the inequality $$\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}<y$$

Also, $f(x)=e^{\frac{x}{2}}$ satisfies all given conditions. But can there be a proper solution or proof.

What could be the biggest value of k

Comment: Check [here](https://prase.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol9910.html).

Comment: If $f(x)=e^{cx}$ where $0<c<1$ then $f''' = c^3f < f$ and $f' = cf < f$.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3744510/42969) asks for the best possible constant $k$, and demonstrates that  $k \le 1.5^{1/3} \approx 1.694$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show that $f'(x)<2f(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364314/how-to-show-that-fx2fx)

Comment: Yes. It does answer