# If $f(x), f'(x), f''(x), f'''(x)>0$ and $f'''(x)≤f(x)$ then prove that $f'(x)<2f(x)$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, inequality

Let $f$ be a real function with a continuous third derivative such that $f(x), f'(x), f''(x), f'''(x)$ are positive for all $x$. Suppose $f'''(x)≤f(x)$ for all $x$ then prove that $f'(x)<2f(x)$ for all $x$.

I don't know where to start for this one. Any hints for how to start would be helpful

Comment: 1999 putnam!:Does this answer your question? [How to show that $f'(x)<2f(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364314/how-to-show-that-fx2fx)

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore can you give some explanation for how we made this conclusion? $\int_{-\infty}^x \left(\int_{-\infty}^tf'''(s) \, ds \right) \, dt=\int_{-\infty}^x(x-s)f'''(s) \,$

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore I also did a little searching and found this alternate solution. I find it better than the solution you shared and the one on Kedlaya's website so you might want to have a look as well if you didn't already https://prase.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol9910.html

Comment: @A thank you!${}$